# How to load scripts into a python interpreter session, and letting python start the interactive mode?

Tags: python

I'ld like one of these:

1. Starting python with a script like `python my_routines.py` and let python enter the interactive state while the code in `my_routines.py` have been loaded/run.
2. Starting python in the interactive mode and loading in some convenient(short and easy to remember) way `my_routines.py`

the idea is, of course, that I want to preload some stuff and then play around with it in the interactive mode.

Suggestions involving loading a module (`python -m ....`) don't have to apply ;-)

Looking forward to your ideas!

Twan

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To continue in REPL *after* running the script, run it with `python -i test.py`, where `-i` stands for *interactive*.

For loading from inside the REPL, you could use `exec`, but your best bet is to use `ipython` and its `%load` command. (ipython is an improved repl, so you should be using that anyway)

Comment: Ah, of course, the -i option forgot that one. Thanks.
The `exec` is a good tip. Sadly in the current application `ipython` is out of the question. Thanks!

Comment: ipython is better? This is the first I hear of this.